# Angular material - move sidenav to left to populate another relative panel

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-animate

I have a button "Add inputs", clicking on which populates a sidenav having multiple inputs and a "edit" button to the side of it like

```
input1  <(edit)>
input2  <(edit)>
```

On click of the edit button, the properties of the respective input variable should be populated (type, default value) by moving the sidenav to left.

```
input1|-> type    _______
input2|   default _______
               <(Done)>
```

And on lick of "Done", the properties panel collapses and the initial inputs sidenav is moved to right (original position)

This is duplicate of [Slide a sidenav to left on a button click and populate another panel there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023251/slide-a-sidenav-to-left-on-a-button-click-and-populate-another-panel-there/44023358#44023358)...... Reposting as need suggestions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slide a sidenav to left on a button click and populate another panel there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023251/slide-a-sidenav-to-left-on-a-button-click-and-populate-another-panel-there)

Comment: @alphapilgrim yes it is. No suggestions there too :( And stuck very badly

Comment: I recommend you add a fiddle to your original question. be more inclined to help if other users didn't have to prototype this on their own.